How allow github actions to access database on vnet
I have setup a web app + database in azure and I am trying to deploy my code via github actions in the deployment center. I have added the connection string to my database in github secrets and I get an erro:
[22:54:57] ERROR (payload): Error: cannot connect to Postgres. Details: getaddrinfo 
ENOTFOUND myapp-database-server.postgres.database.azure.com
error Command failed with exit code 1.

In reality this makes sense because how could github actions check my database exists if its behind a vnet. So I am curious how can I fix this issue without removing my vnet and making my db public?
One option noted in comments is runners. I found this code tto add to my yml file:
      - name: Whitelist GitHub Runner IP
    uses: azure/CLI@v1
    with:
      inlineScript: |
        set -eu
        agentIP=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org/)
        az storage account network-rule add \
          --resource-group "${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}" \
          --account-name "${{ secrets.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}" \
          --ip-address $agentIP
        sleep 300

My question is how can I add an ip exception to a vnet? Do I need to setup a firewall with it somehow and allow ip access?

Have you reviewed the relevant GitHub documentation on this topic?

I saw that but it looks like only enterprise users can do runners

Why not use Azure Pipelines instead?

You have two options. First option is to create a VM and install a self-hosted runner on it. The VM should either located in your VNET or is connected to a paired VNET/is able to route to that network.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners
The other option is, that you enable the public endpoint of the database with "Selected Networks"
Then you can use the script you have to add an IP exception for the github public runner to your database. (Do not forget to remove it afterwards)
az sql server firewall-rule create -g mygroup -s myserver -n myrule --start-ip-address 1.2.3.4 --end-ip-address 5.6.7.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server/firewall-rule?view=azure-cli-latest
From your posted code (haven't tested it)
- name: Whitelist GitHub Runner IP
uses: azure/CLI@v1
with:
  inlineScript: |
    set -eu
    agentIP=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org/)
    az sql server firewall-rule create -g "${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}" -s "${{ secrets.SQL_SERVER_NAME }}" -n ghrunner --start-ip-address $agentIP --end-ip-address $agentIP
    sleep 300


If you had to choose which option would you use?

It really depends on your regulatory/compliance requirements.
Personally I do not like to have to manage runners. So, if the security compromise is possible for you, use the public endpoint with an IP exception as it is operational wise easier and also cheaper. Use (managed/federated) identity when connection to the database as it is more secure than database users. in If you need to ensure that the database is never exposed to the internet and you need to guarantee network controls use the runner option.

So when you choose the wep app + database option you cannot choose the public endpoint option in settings/network. It is grayed out and only private access is accessible. Not sure if there is a way around this or I have to start a brand new database and web app separately.

Ah, got you. Never have worked with that option before. Please check this documentation, which seems to cover your question https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-app-service-sqldb-dotnetcore?tab=readme-ov-file#how-is-database-migrations-automated

Or chose the private runner option

I went with the private runner option after all. Was not so bad to setup.

I was able to get the private runners working and I created a Vnet which the runners connect to then I peer this with each app's vnet. THe issue is if each app is setup on default 10.0.0.0/16 address then there is overlap so peering gives me a warning about the overlap. Anyway to fix this easily if I want to scale to more than one app? The web app + database option defaults the vnets to 10.0.0.0 so curious if I need to start changing these one by one to 10.x.0.0 basically.

You should plan your network accordingly. 10.0.0.0/16 is way to big for a single application. Use subnetting to split it up. Start for example with subnets with /28 networks. And maybe a maximum of /22 for a vnet

could I use /28 for both? Sorry bit of a network noob. So if I had three vents then what would the address be and the subnet I set for each? If you can tell me that il be able to research this more how that all works. Kind of understanding /28 and /24 etc but not sure how it all fits together for this scenario since you don’t set starting and ending ip like a home network (or maybe you can lol?)

A good way to plan your Azure Footprint is always the CAF (It is much, but worth it at the end) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/
But assuming you assign 10.100.0.0/16 for your Azure region (assuming you might and with additional which will then be 10.101.0.0/16.
Assuming this, and maybe going with /26 and /25 subnets for VNETs (depending on the size/needs) you could break it down quite easily. Create one Hub VNET (which might hold VPN GW, Firewall, etc in the future) - 10.100.0.0/24 and then start by creating further vnets you pair with this hub vnet.

But to start quick in your limited case, create two networks - one for the runner, one for the database. Maybe go with 10.100.10.0/26 for the runner (to leave some room for some shared hub networks you might want to add later) and 10.100.10.64/26 the database.
